# Setting up a wifi access point using an external wifi adapter

Tags: ssh, access-point

Im trying to set up my RPi model 4 b 2Gb to act as an access point. Im using the built in chip in monitor mode using [nexmon_csi](https://github.com/nexmonster/nexmon_csi/tree/pi-5.4.51) library. The library is tested and working fine. When I plug in the new wifi adapter to set it up as an access point using this [tutorial](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/), I stop being able to access the RPi using ssh and the AP network doesn't start as well. I'm a bit new to the Raspberry pi so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `the new wifi adapter` - add some details of this adapter. make/model VID:PID etc

Comment: It's a  TP-Link TL-WN725N Nano. Also, the library I'm using to get the monitor mode is killing wpa_supplicant so I guess that's the problem. I tried setting the AP without the nexmon_csi (monitor mode library) and it worked. Is there a way to set an AP without spa_supplicant?

Comment: wpa_supplicant is used for wifi clients - using the tp-link as an access point should not require wpa_supplicant